# putting a shortcut to dock

Tags: macos, dock

I created an aliases for a binary file (which runs in terminal) and want to put the aliases (shortcut) to dock. However, I can't drag&drop it to the dock. Is there a way to put the aliases to the dock?

Comment: Maybe you need Automator?

Answer (score 3):

You can put aliases on the Dock to the right of the separator line. Only applications can go left.